# ActiveCollab Update invoice status using API v1

Tags: api, activecollab

Following the [Documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/invoicing/invoices/invoices.html) I've tried to update the status of an invoice using the API.

I've tried to send

`{"single": {"status": "$status"}}` as well as just

`{"status": "$status"}` to

`PUT api/v1/invoices/$invoiceId`

where $status is `canceled` (also tried with `paid`) but without success. Although I get a http status code of 200 back, in all cases. How can I "cancel" an invoice? And how about sending an "Illegal Request" status code or something, if the request fails?

Thanks,
Martin.

{"application":"ActiveCollab","version":"6.0.6"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send PUT request on `api/v1/invoices/1/cancel` to cancel an invoice. No params needed.